# Oracle database date column does not show full date in php

Tags: php, oracle, date, oracle11g

I have date column and date value is set the format : DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS
and when I execute sql script from sqldeveloper I can see the date like
 16-MAR-15 20:40:47. But when I want to get this value with php :

```
$currentDATE=$row['DATE'];
echo gettype($row['DATE']);
echo $currentDATE;
```

I see the result as 
string16-MAR-15
How can I see full date information in php page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be due to the nls_date_format settings on your Oracle client. It's also a really good demonstration as to why your SQL scripts should not rely on implicit conversions.

You have two options:

1. (recommended) Update your sql script so that the sql statement outputs `to_char(<date column>, '<your date format>')`
2. alter your default nls_date_format setting by running `alter session set nls_date_format= '<your date format>';` just after connecting to SQL*Plus.

The first option is by far the best option; it means anyone who has to run that script will see the same results, without having to faff around with the nls_date_format setting.

Comment: when I changed my query in php as SELECT to_date(B.issueDate ,' DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS') FROM BorrowedBy B; date is shown as NULL

Comment: You want to use `TO_CHAR(b.issueDate, 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS')` not `TO_DATE()`.

Comment: Yes, apologies; my original answer had to_date instead of to_char. Slip of the brain! When you run the query directly in SQL*Plus yourself (ie. not via PHP, what does that select statement show?

Comment: What about if you do: `select to_char(B.issueDate ,' DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS') issuedate FROM BorrowedBy`? N.B. It is important you use `to_char` when you're converting something that's in DATE datatype to a string so that you can view it in the relevant format. If you do a to_date on something that's already a date, then you force Oracle to do an implicit conversion - twice - and that could cause information to be lost, as the implicit conversion depends on your nls_date_format setting.

Comment: When I query in sqldeveloper SELECT to_date(issueDate,'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS') FROM BorrowedBy ; it shows  16-MAR-15 20:40:47

Comment: And did you try running `select to_char(B.issueDate ,' DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS') issuedate FROM BorrowedBy` in PHP? I suspect the issue is that your PHP query is looking for a column called `ISSUEDATE`, which the column was no longer called due to the `to_char` around it. So, you have to alias the column back to `ISSUEDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

> I have date column and date value is set the format : DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS

Make sure that while displaying a DATE you explicitly convert the **DATE** into **string** using **TO_CHAR** along with the desired **format mask**.

The date format which you see, depends on your **locale-specific NLS settings**.

Remember,

1. For date calculations, convert a string to date using **TO_DATE**. If it is a date type, then leave as it is.
2. To display a `DATE` value in your desired format, convert it into a string using **TO_CHAR** and proper **format mask**.